# Why aren't C++ Lambda Expressions Working?

Tags: c++

I'm using Mac OS. I've installed the most recent Xcode Command Line Tools.

I'm trying to learn C++. I've been working through some code examples, but programs with lambda expressions won't compile for some reason.

I've attached some example code and the error message below.

```
#include <cstdio> 

    int main() { 

           auto first = [] (int x) { 

                  printf("%d \n", x); 
           }; 
    }
```

I'm not allowed to attach pictures into Stack Overflow yet.

Here is my error message:

```
error: expected expression 

auto first = [ ] (int x)
```

The compiler points to the square brackets.

My IDE doesn't show any problems.

Comment: What compiler and command are you using to compile this code? Some compilers still require special flags to turn on "new" features from 2011.

Comment: The code you posted seems to work fine https://godbolt.org/z/de99TTxhr . I guess you are compiling with the older C++ versions which don't support lambda exp https://godbolt.org/z/P3r88T6TE

Comment: Probably that you're compiling to an old standard as pointed out by Silvio. But please post the whole error next time - "The compiler points to the square brackets." is _not_ a compile error.

Comment: xcode is an ide, a fancy editor. What matters is the compiler you use to compile the code.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments! Another user posted an answer, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are compiling with g++, by default it is using c++98. And the 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension. so you need to tell the compiler to use the c++11/17.

compile your srcs using the following:

`g++ -std=c++11 yourfile.cpp`

Comment: And lambdas in general are C++11 as well, so even if we could (somehow) get rid of the `auto`, we still need C++11.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked. I'm new to C++, and coding in general. I've been using the g++ command to compile all of my programs. Is there another way to compile code that will use more recent versions of C++?  Or do we have to always include the C++ version when compiling with g++?

Comment: @ilt_coding - It's generally better to be explicit in the flags you use when compiling. GCC changes the default setting with time. GCC 6.1 defaults to C++14. And GCC 11 defaults to C++17.